# Check if page exist or 404 using php

Tags: php, http, http-status-code-404

Hi I have created a script using php to verify whether the page exist or its a 404 not found means invalid url the problem which I am facing at moment is weather the link exist or not in both case it is showing that the url is valid I am not sure if I am using a wrong approach or am I missing something below is the code which I am using

```
$file_headers = @get_headers('https://instagram.com/p/xyz');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($file_headers);
echo "</pre>";
if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = 0;
    $error = '<div class="message">Provided url does not exists.</div>';
} else {
    $error = '';
    $exists = 1;
}

echo $exists;
```

I also tried to achieved this with curl but the problem is that with curl I am getting null response clean blank page nothing less nothing more below is how I am using with curl

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($handle);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

print_r($httpCode);

curl_close($handle);
```

Comment: That URL generates a 301 redirect, not a 404. You may be better off using [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) with the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option.

Comment: I tried to use curl but I got blank response nothing

Comment: You have to use it the specific way mentioned by Alex. Please edit the question to show exactly what code you used, and what status code the request returned. It's entirely possible that a 404 might return an empty response body, with the problem noticeable only by looking at the status code in the response headers

Comment: I updated my question please check my question I have added the code

Comment: Your curl code outputs 301 for me, as expected.

Comment: with above new added curl code let suppose if the page is found it gives me 403 error and if i put invalid page name it shows me same 403 which is really much strange

Comment: @AlexHowansky the thing is that f you notice https://instagram.com/p/xyz this does not exist so 403 error is pretty much strange 
https://a940cf0eb0.nxcli.net/buy-instagram-followers/ this is a valid url by using this it shows 403 
https://a940cf0eb0.nxcli.net/buy124 this is 404 not found but still this one shows 403 isn't this strange

Comment: `xyz` is a valid instagram user, as can be seen at `instagram.com/xyz`. I'm not sure what your goal is or why you're using that extra `/p/` in your URL, but everything you're showing here is functioning as expected.

Comment: please see my last comment in both url 1 is 404 and other one is valid both shows 403 does that make sense ??
instagram.com/p/xyz is a 404 post not found there is no such post with this url how can this be a valid ?
a940cf0eb0.nxcli.net/buy124 this should be a 404 as there is not page exist

Comment: Pages behave differently based on many factors, like whether they're being hit by a curl or a javascript-capable browser. If you additionally enable `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` you can see exactly what requests are being made in the redirect chain, and what headers result.

Comment: @AlexHowansky so how do I do that ?

Comment: It's an option you can pass to cURL, like the other options you've added in your code, via curl_set_opt()

Comment: can you show me example please so i can test it out if you could help me

Comment: Seriously? `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`. As I said, it's literally just like your existing cURL option in your code. And you could even google many examples very easily already... U+1F926. Also - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: ohh sorry i did not knew to set because new to curl sorry for that

Comment: Being new is fine, but the whole point of having documentation and existing examples is exactly so that new people can read them and use them without needing to ask about every single detail :-)